# Calculating count of timestamp

Tags: python, collections, count

I am interested in calculating an event with timestamp that occurred five times in 30 days.

I have a created a function and I do feel this is nowhere near pythonic.

Is there way I can use collections or iterator or lambda.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
def has_five_or_more_in_ANY_30_days(timestamps):

    for i in range(timestamps):
        from_value = timestamps[i]
        to_value = from_value + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)

        counts = 0
        for ts in timestamps:
            if ts > from_value and ts < to_value:
                counts += 1
                if counts >=5:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

timestamps = [ 1416182478, 1416182479, 1416182480, 1416182481, 1416182481, 1416182481, 1416182481,1416182481,1416182481,1416182482,1416182483,1416182484, 1416182485, 1416182486,1416182487, 1416182488,1416182489, 1416182490 ]

print has_five_or_more_in_ANY_30_days( timestamps )
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your current approach? And what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: The code does not work and secondly I am asking is there a way I can optimize?

Comment: @Paddy Explain, in a bit more detail, exactly what you're trying to achieve What are these events? What kind of timestamps are you trying to add?

Comment: I am not sure why the above problem is not clear. I will explain. I am try to aggregate timestamp and I am trying to find the events happened multiple times for a specific time period. These events are captured from an instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not work for you because, you are returning `False` in the inner loop itself, so you always return `False` , since you initialized `count` as 0 , and in the first iteration ou only increase count by 1 , so count is 1 , and it is not greater than 5, so you return `False` . For your particular code to work, you need to move the `return False` to outside the outer loop , directly inside the function , the `else` block should not be there.

---

Given that you can simplify the code , by using the following method -

1. First sort the timestamps from lowest to highest.
2. Then check the difference between each timestamp , and add it to a value, do this for every 5 consecutive items. At the end, if the addition of difference of 5 consecutive timestamps is less than `30 * 24 * 60 * 60` , that means those 5 dates fall within the 30 days range and you can return True at that time.
3. If no such matches found, return False.

Example code -

```
def has_five_or_more_in_ANY_30_days(timestamps):
    tssorted = sorted(timestamps)
    time_to_check = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    for i in range(0,len(tssorted)-5):
        time_diff = 0
        for j in range(i+1,i+5):
            time_diff += tssorted[j] - tssorted[i]
        if time_diff < time_to_check:
            return True
    return False
```